# Python Qt4 Prevent JavaScript Alerts/Pop-ups

Tags: javascript, python, qt4

I'm automating some browser tests using Qt4. Since I need to inspect some JavaScript DOM elements I cannot just pull the source page as text since the JS needs to be loaded into a browser so the objects may be searched.

The issue is that if there is an alert in the HTML it pops up and prevents my script from continuing automatically. I've included a sample python script demonstrating the issue (although not the search part of my app). The browser object does not even need to show the page for the JS alert to execute on the "page load". Any way to prevent this or a suggested workaround using Qt4?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

html = """

<html>
<frameset cols="1%,99%">
<frame name="frame1" id="frame1" src="">
<frame name='frame2' id='frame2' src='javascript:var testVar="Prevent Me!"; alert(testVar);'> 
</frameset>
</html>

"""

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
browser = QWebView()
browser.setHtml(html)
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two items:
1. Use QWebPage instead of QWebView()
2. Class must be overridden

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import * 

class QWebPageOverride(QWebPage):
    def javaScriptAlert(browser, frame, message):
            """Notifies session for alert, then pass."""
            print "signal for javaScriptAlert (class) fired"

html = """

<html>
<frameset cols="1%,99%">
<frame name="frame1" id="frame1" src="">
<frame name='frame2' id='frame2' src='javascript:var testVar="Prevent Me!"; alert(testVar);'> 
</frameset>
</html>

"""

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
browser = QWebPageOverride()
frame = browser.mainFrame()
frame.setHtml(html)
print "No popup"

browser2 = QWebPage()
frame2 = browser2.mainFrame()
frame2.setHtml(html)
print "After Popup"

exit()
```